# Truffle: { Error: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1! at module.exports

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-test, truffle-deployment, constructor

I am trying to execute the following smart contract using Truffle:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;
 
 contract Phishable {
     address public owner;
     constructor (address _owner) public{
         owner = _owner;
     }
     function () external payable {} 
     function withdrawAll(address payable _recipient) public {
         require(tx.origin == owner);
         _recipient.transfer(address(this).balance);
     } }
```

==
Following is my script:

```
const vic= artifacts.require("Phishable");
 console.log("Point1 ###1")
 const att= artifacts.require("PhishableAtt");
 console.log("Point2 ###2")
 const vicobj = await vic.new();
 console.log("Point3 ###1")
```

When I execute the script, I am getting the following output:

```
$ truffle exec toolreent3.js
Using network 'development'.

Point1 ###1
Point2 ###2
{ Error: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!
    at module.exports (/home/zulfi/Truffle_programs/txorigin_assertion_TechyTech_tool/toolreent3.js:400:42)
```

My 2_deploy_contracts.js is:

```
const Phishable  = artifacts.require("Phishable");
module.exports = function(deployer) {

deployer.deploy(Phisable);
}
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line `const vicobj = await vic.new();`. The function new() requires a  parameter such as `{from: accounts[0]}` .

Comment: @Yonjian, please tell me about the arguments for the migration file also i.e. 2_deploy_contracts.js